# What hypothesis test would be suitable to reject that two nominal random variables are independent on each other?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, classification, correlation, categorical-data

I have a list of word tokens extracted from descriptions of 100 images. Based on the picture's visual features I classified each picture into 3 classes: Top, Middle, Bottom.

I created a count table from that which looks like:

```
Index Word Top Middle Bottom
343 Pair    1   0   0
344 Partial 0   1   0
345 Pattern 0   2   1
346 Perfect 0   0   1
347 Petite  0   1   0
```

I would like to investigate if there is a "correlation" between a certain word and which category it will belong to so that I can predict this visual feature based on the descriptions of the pictures.

I initially tried using Chi-squared, but to my understanding, Chi-squared is simply a hypothesis test whether the two random variables are independent or not. Rather here, I assume that they are NOT independent, but I want to quantify which word they depend on more. (I hope that it makes sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a chi-square test is a good start. In the null hypothesis framework we usually work from the assumption that there is no relationship (or that variables are independent). If your test came out significant you have reason to believe that there is indeed a relationship between those two variables.

As a rough first indication the direction of the effect can be typically identified by comparing the outcomes of the observed table with the expected table. If you find for example that the combination Perfect-Bottom occurs more often than expected, then apparently those two categories are associated.

Should you want to do more sophisticated analysis you can do something like a multinomial logit model.